# $n$-th derivative of the prolate spheroidal function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, derivatives, wavelets

For a given real number $c>0$ define functions $\left(\psi_{k,c}(\cdot)\right)_{k\ge0}$,  as an eigenfunctions of the Sturm-Liouville operators $L_c$ defined
$$
L_c(\psi)=(1-x^2)\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}-2x \frac{d\psi}{dx}-c^2x^2\psi
$$
( in fact, $\psi_{k,c}^{(n)}$ is called the prolate spheroidal wave function).

I would like to find the $n$-th derivative of the prolate spheroidal function $\psi_{k,c}^{(n)}(x)$ .

Any referense r ideas will be very helpful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In which form are you seeking to express the derivatives? A power series? Maybe a series of Legendre functions? Perhaps letting $\psi=z^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}z^{-k}$ could get you started?

Comment: Any form would be good for me. What is $c_k$ in your formula? Thank you.

Comment: this is a standard beginning of derivation of a solution to Legendre's equation. $c_k$ are the coefficients to be determined. You may consider also expansion in associated Legendre functions, though this leads to a quite complicated [recurrence relation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProlateSpheroidalCoordinates.html)

Comment: cross-posted to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98442/n-th-derivative-of-the-prolate-spheroidal-function

Comment: Nothing listed [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/30), sadly; IIRC the derivatives are not expressible in terms of the spheroidal functions, and are thus treated as new functions in their own right.